# Can't see my navigation bar + text on footer

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to make a simple web site, but i ran into some problems so far. The problem is that i want a navigationbar with 3 links, which should be in color #FFFFFF.

It should be placed inside the header where i got the title to the left, and to the right there should be 3 links which should go (in an animated way) down to the articles.

It should look like this:

---

```
      <h1>Title</h1>                                About   Price   Contact
```

---

```
                                    Content here
```

---

```
                                    Copyright 2014
```

---

My code so far:

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="container">
    <header>
    <br><br>    
        <h1 style="color:white">Title</h1>  
    </header>

    <nav>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Price</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>

    <div id="content">
        <br>
    <p>Content goes here</p>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <footer>
            <h4 style="color:white">Copyright 2014</h4>
        </footer>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, img, form {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
}

header {
    height: 130px;
    background: #484848;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Helvetica;

}

nav {



}


#footer {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;    
    background: #909090;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    position: auto;

}

#content {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 1500px;
    top: 100px;
    background: #FFFFFF;    
    font-family: Helvetica;
    text-align: center;

}
```

Can any tell me why i can't see the links i created in the first place? also the h4 header in the footer is also not displayed ;S

Comment: There are a couple of problems with the code. As you are using `position: fixed` the header will overlap the nav. This can be solved with z-index but I would want to solve this another way.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with you codes is that you're using `position: fixed` for your header and your links are outside this tag. So your links are actually being displayed behind your header. If you place them inside that should solve the problem.

I think that you want something like the following: http://jsfiddle.net/G5JRK/

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I currently found just by messing around with it in Jfiddle is by setting the header's z-index to something less than 0.